# Getting remote file size

Tags: vb.net, webrequest, filesize, visual-studio-2010

What is the best way to get a remote file size in vb.net? Recently I was using this code:

```
        Dim Request As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim Response As System.Net.WebResponse
        Dim FileSize As Integer
        Request = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://my-url.com/file.exe")
        Request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
        Response = Request.GetResponse
        FileSize = Response.ContentLength
```

From some time it doesn't work properly because it is giving a invalid file size.

Putty says: 1.240.214 bytes (valid),
vb.net's `WebRequest` says: 1.246.314 bytes (invalid!)

It looks like WebRequest is using some kind of cache...
Is there a better way to obtain remote file size?

Comment: Just wondering -- could the web request possibly calculating in response headers to the size of the payload whereas putty is not?

Answer (score 1):

How about you make a HEAD request, like this:

```
Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://my-url.com/file.exe")
req.Method = "HEAD"

Using resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Dim ContentLength As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(resp.Headers.[Get]("Content-Length"), ContentLength) Then
    ' Use ContentLength variable here 
    End If
End Using
```

Does that give you the same result as PuTTY?

Comment: `ContentLength` returns 1.246.314 bytes , which means its the same invalid size as of `WebRequest`. Putty's `ls -l` is giving `1.240.214` bytes, WinSCP properties of the file are giving `1.240.214` bytes output as well...

Comment: Can you not just take the raw data from both and compare to see what's the actual difference instead of trying to guess?

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston There is no guessing! What could be a difference between ONE file? None. It just depends on the local - putty's, and remote file size. All request to the file from the local machine are giving valid file size, while remote computers are giving fake file size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Imports System.Net    
    
    Try
       Dim theSeekRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.somesite.co.za/filetocheck.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
       theSeekRequest.Timeout = 10000  ' 10 seconds
       Dim theSeekResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(theSeekRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
       theSeekResponse = theSeekRequest.GetResponse
       Dim SitefileSize As Long = theSeekResponse.ContentLength
    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Remote request timed out.")
    End Try
```